# I am trying to loop inserting elements into a set if they intersect, but it isn't giving me what im looking for

Tags: c++

all and all2 are both string sets. all is filled with actors in movie1, and all2 is empty. my loop is supposed to check if an actor in movie2 is also in movie1, and if they are then to insert that actor in all2. However my code is just outputting all the actors in movie2.

```
all = imdb.find_actors_in_a_movie(matchedMovie1);
for (auto i = actors_in_movie2.begin(); i != actors_in_movie2.end(); i++)
{
    if (all.count(*m) > 0)
    {
        all2.insert(*m);
    }
}
```

all holds Christopher Walken, Leonardo DiCaprio, Martin Sheen, Tom Hanks

actors_in_movie2 holds Greg Kinnear, Meg Ryan, Parker Posey, Tom Hanks

The output I receive is Greg Kinnear, Meg Ryan, Parker Posey, Tom Hanks.

It should only be outputting Tom Hanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a loop, use [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> all = {"Joe", "Jack", "Mary", "Frank"};
    std::set<std::string> actors_in_movie2 = {"James", "Jack", "Philip", "Frank"};
    std::set<std::string> all2;
    std::set_intersection(actors_in_movie2.begin(),
                        actors_in_movie2.end(),
                        all.begin(),
                        all.end(),
                        std::inserter(all2, all2.end()));

   for (auto& n : all2)
      std::cout << n << "\n";                            
}
```

Output:

```
Frank
Jack
```

Since a `std::set` stores the names sorted, and `std::set_intersection` requires a sorted sequence to work correctly, using `std::set_intersection` is a ready-made solution.

[Live Example using your input](https://godbolt.org/z/d4aK386no)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However I don't think I'm supposed to be using std::set_intersection. It gives me an error that 'set_intersection' is not a member of 'std', and I cannot change the header files.

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`.?  Second, any limitations are to be posted up-front in the question.  The answer posted is how you accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.  The code in the answer can be copied and pasted in any standard C++ 11 and above compiler, and it will compile successfully and work successfully.